# How to allow an async task to run for a given amount of seconds?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

So I created a task handler. I want to have it run for some predetermined guaranteed amount of time, then I want to do some of my stuff, and only then do I need the result of the handler to be awaited. Something like:

```
var th = TaskCreator();
th.awaitFor(5000);
//do some work
var result = await th;
```

So how can an async task run for a given number of seconds?

Comment: What is the `var th`? Is it a `Task`? Please write specific types on StackOverflow. We can't hover the mouse over the `var`, and see the type of the variable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `WhenAny` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-7.0)):

```cs
var th = TaskCreator();
await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), th);
//do some work
var result = await th;
```

This will stop awaiting when either of the tasks completes, meaning that you can then do your other work, and reawait `th` at the end to wait for its completion (or just get the result if it has already completed).

If your `TaskCreator` method does a lot of synchronous work before going async, you might want to first call `await Task.Yield();` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=net-7.0)) inside the `TaskCreator` method before using the above code.

Comment: This will probably give you [a warning](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33805 "Detect non-cancelable Task.Delay passed to Task.WhenAny") on .NET 8.

Answer (score 5):

The preferred mechanism here would be to implement cancellation in your `TaskCreator`. This provides multiple benefits:

- it allows the work in `TaskCreator` to *actually stop happening* when the timeout has happened
- it allows flexibility to future cancellation reasons

Example:

```cs
using var cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
cs.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var result = await TaskCreator(cs.Token);
```

where your `TaskCreator` would presumably look something like:

```cs
async Task<int> TaskCreator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

and where you *actually use* `cancellationToken` in `TaskCreator`, either directly (usually via `.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` or `.Register(...)`) or indirectly (passing it to downstream awaitable APIs).

Answer (score 3):

[Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74489118/263693) is ideal. If you aren't able to add cancellation for some reason, you can use `WaitAsync`:

```
var th = TaskCreator();
var result = await th.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

`WaitAsync` is similar to the common `WhenAny` approach, but without leaking timers.

Note that both `WaitAsync` and `WhenAny` do not cancel the *operation*; they just cancel the *(a)wait*. Marc's answer will properly cancel the operation.

Comment: Something not entirely obvious is that in case the `timeout` elapses before the completion of the task, the [`Task.WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync) propagates a `TimeoutException`.